# How to protect XAMPP htdoc folder

Tags: php, xampp

I am a Finance & A/C person, but I am learning PHP and I have created an application in PHP, which I am running on my office PC (Windows 8) through XAMPP.

Now I have to put this application at my headquarters, where I will not be present physically to start the application daily and application will be accessed by LAN.

I want to protect the htdoc folder so that another person can start XAMPP,  but cannot access htdocs folder.

I have tried to create an Admin User and a Guest User on the same computer
and share the htdoc only with the Admin user, but in that case, the Guest User is not able to start Apache.

How can I do this?

Comment: with my knowledge, It's not possible or even if it's possible, its not safe to do so. imagine the guest users runs an application on the machine which causes the system to freeze or runs a heavy processing application. these will cause your web server to serve you application very slow or even not respond. it's better to put your code on a machine which will only be used for purpose.

Comment: I agree with you ,But suppose I have logged in as Admin and also running xampp with administrative right.   Then Whether there is some folder lock kind of application which can restrict access of htdocs folder

Comment: yes, but you still can not avoid unwanted slow performance by the user using same machine or even system restarts in the middle of server usage by other users on the lan. if for budget purposes you want to use same machine for both user and server, i suggest using some kind of [virtual machine](http://lifehacker.com/5714966/five-best-virtual-machine-applications) so that users on the same machine can not interfere between each others processes.